# How to get LinkedIn profile position/company intrustry code?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm developing an application using LinkedIn api, in documentation it is stated that company/industry value should be one of acronyms described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/reference-tables/industry-codes but instead of that I'm getting full industry name like "Information Technology and Services", is it possible to get it in "tech" format?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was using V1 api ;)